# How to make a custom animator work in Kotlin (animating the alpha property)

Tags: android, kotlin, alpha, animator

I want to animate the `ALPHA` property on an `ImageView` by means of an `AnimatorSet` (I actually have two animations, but I'm using the alpha one only for now in order to check if it works) I'm using `Kotlin` (and I'm new to it)
I have a layout with the ImageView inside, an xml with the `AnimatorSet` and a `Kotlin` class related to the layout.

Here are some options I've already tried, all of them in the `onCreate` method and making use of the `Kotlin extensions`:

```
mLogo.post {
        slideUpAndFadeIn = AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(this, 
R.animator.slide_up_and_fade_in) as AnimatorSet
        slideUpAndFadeIn.duration = 250
        slideUpAndFadeIn.setTarget(mLogo)
        slideUpAndFadeIn.start()
}
```

---

```
mLogo.animate().apply {
        interpolator = LinearInterpolator()
        duration = 500
        alpha(1f)
        startDelay = 1000
        start()
    }
```

---

```
val objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mLogo, View.ALPHA, 0.0f, 1.0f)
    objectAnimator.duration = 250
    objectAnimator.interpolator = AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator()
    objectAnimator.start()
```

This is the code as I have it now:

### MainActivity.kt

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var slideUpAndFadeIn : AnimatorSet

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    slideUpAndFadeIn = AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(this, 
    R.animator.slide_up_and_fade_in) as AnimatorSet
    slideUpAndFadeIn.duration = 250
    slideUpAndFadeIn.setTarget(mLogo)
    slideUpAndFadeIn.start()
    }
}
```

### activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:gravity="center">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/mLogo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/main_logo"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/dimen_margin_main_logo"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

### slide_up_and_fade_in.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:ordering="together">
    <objectAnimator
        android:propertyName="translationY"
        android:valueFrom="1"
        android:valueTo="50"
        android:valueType="intType"
        android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/fast_out_linear_in"/>

<objectAnimator
        android:propertyName="alpha"
        android:valueFrom="0.0"
        android:valueTo="1.0"
        android:valueType="floatType"/>
</set>
```

The app doesn't crash, so there's no NullPointerException, but the animation doesn't work. It never "fades in".
Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'visibility' and 'alpha' are different attributes. As you are animating alpha you should use `android:alpha="0"` in your xml layout instead of `android:visibility="invisible"`